# Google Maps Issue Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have searched all over google for a solution however this seems a new one? I am trying to implement google maps API on a site however I keep getting the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined

My JS is as follows:

```
        var map;
        function initialize(location) {
            var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
            var latLng;
            if (location == 0) {
                latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.066356, 1.102388);
            }
            else if (location == 1) {
                latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.672492, 1.232196);
            }
            else if (location == 2) {
                latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.207607, 0.123017);
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
                center: latLng,
                zoom: 14,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'tilesloaded', addMarker(location));

        }

        function addMarker(location) {
            var latLng;
            if (location == 0) {
                latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.066703, 1.113573);
            }
            else if (location == 1) {
                latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.672492, 1.232196);
            }
            else if (location == 2) {
                latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.207607, 0.123017);
            }
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                map: map
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            initialize(0);
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, can't believe I missed that one ;-)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In this line

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'tilesloaded', addMarker(location));
```

You're calling the function addMarker instead of passing it as a function reference. Therefore, addMarker is getting executed before map is defined. Try changing that line to:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {addMarker(location)});
```

Comment: Very usefull tip. In my case, I had the same error, regarding an addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed')

Comment: Happened to me as well and fixed by using inline function. tks

Answer (score 6):

The problem is you're invoking the function `addMarker` which you should be supplying a callback.  Change your call to the following

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() { addMarker(location) });
```

Right now you're instead directly invoking `addMarker` which returns no value.  This means you're effectively passing `undefined` to the API and the google library is hitting the error attempting to invoke your callback